# creating List within a list in recurrsion from string python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a list from a string 
input string
`st = "zzabcxzghfxx"`
the list is enclosed in 'z' and 'x'

this is my attempt to create a recursive function

```
st = "zzabcxzghfxx"

def createlist(strin):
    l1=[]
    for i in st:
        if(i=='x'):
            createlist(strin)
        elif(i=='z'):
            l1.append(i)        
    return(l1)
```

following is the desired output:`"[[abc][ghf]]"`

`string = "zzabcxzghzfxx"=> [[abc][ghzf]]"`

Comment: `st.strip('zz').strip('xx') `is the same as doing `st.strip('xz')` @jojo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

st = "zzabcxzghfxx"
print(re.findall(r"z+(.*?)(?=x)", st))
#or print([[i] for i in re.findall(r"z+(.*?)(?=x)", st)])
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', 'ghf']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `strip` the trailing `x` and `z` and `split` on `xz`:

```
st.strip('xz').split('xz')
# ['abc', 'ghf']
```

Comment: no [[abc][ghf]] list within a list

Comment: Not sure why you'd want that... but change with `[[i] for i in st.strip('xz').split('xz')]` @ZombieCoder8

Comment: Does not produce a nested list @hansolo

Comment: @yatu Oh, i see

Comment: I thought of up-voting yours and extend it here as a comment :) `[[s] for s in st.strip('xz').split('xz')]`

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be recursive? Here's a solution using `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby

string = "zzabcxzghfxx"

def is_good_char(char):
    return char not in "zx"

lists = [["".join(char for char in list(group))] for key, group in groupby(string, key=is_good_char) if key]
print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[['abc'], ['ghf']]
```

**EDIT** - Just realized that this might not actually produce the desired behavior. You said:

> [a] list is enclosed in 'z' and 'x'

Which means a sublist starts with 'z' and must end with 'x', yes? In that case the `itertools.groupby` solution I posted will not work exactly. The way it's written now it will generate a new sublist that starts and ends with either 'z' or 'x'. Let me know if this really matters or not.

Comment: ```string = "zzabcxzghzfxx"=>[['abc'], ['gh'], ['f']] ``` when i add extra z in between output shud be [[abc], [ghzf]]

Answer (score -1):

```
st.replace("z", "[").replace("x", "]")
```